# Publish contenttype after activating feature (Office 365)

Tags: content-type, feature, client-object-model, content-type-hub, office-365

I've created a Contenttype and some fields in a visual studio project. They are deployed when activating the "Content types"-feature. But here's the problem: I want them to be deployed to the Content Type HUB (in Office 365). Deploying itself isn't a problem but I also want the content-types to be published, so I can use them in my other sitecollections.

I guess I'll need to do this with the client object model with a feature receiver?
Is there anyone who has an example how to do this? (Or if there's a better way to do this, please say so...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think client side object model is a good idea. I think you need to publish them using code written in a feature receiver. Please see the link below...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaks/archive/2011/09/04/content-type-hub-publishing-and-subscribing-to-content-types-programmatically-c-code.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Hi Here is a example how to create a custom content type and add it to 365

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://anmol-pc");
```

Web web = clientContext.Web;
    ContentTypeCollection contentTypes = web.ContentTypes;
    clientContext.Load(contentTypes);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

```
ContentTypeCreationInformation newConInfo = new ContentTypeCreationInformation();
newConInfo.Name = "MyFirstContentType";
newConInfo.ParentContentType = contentTypes.GetById("add parent content ID");
newConInfo.Group = "My Group";

//Create
ContentType newContent = contentTypes.Add(newConInfo);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: That's not really the problem. I can create the contenttypes, but I don't know how to publish them (It's on the content type hub sitecollection) Thanks anyways